# Multiple Modal Boxes overwritten

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, simplemodal

I have a problem of a simple yet confusing matter. I have two modal boxes with two separate Id's in my page. It's a simple registration and login ones. Thinking behind it was that if I use the same code yet change the id to target them individually would make things work the way I wish them to would do the job yet whenever I modify the content it appears to be identical in both of them. I have a little suspicion of where things are going wrong yet I need some guidance. Please help a girl out.

HTML

```
    <!-- The Modal 1-->
 <div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content 1 -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
 <p>Registration FORM WILL GO HERE..</p>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- The Modal 2-->

<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content 2 -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>LOGIN FORM WILL GO HERE..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

    <script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtnn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you are using the same variable names for both modals, even if your variables  are on different script tags the variables are in the same scope (global) so they are the same variables, http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: Thanks Mate @DavidFlorez